# How do I disable a hover animation until my component's intro animation is complete in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, gsap, framer-motion

I'm using a *useEffect* for my component's intro animation and for my hover animation I'm using whileHover on my component. So essentially I want *whilehover* disabled until the *useEffect* is complete.

What I've tried:

```
const App = () => {

 const [animationComplete, setAnimationComplete] = useState(false);

 useEffect (() => {

 //gsap.to animation....

 setAnimationComplete(true)

 },[]);



return (

<div 
   className="myComponent" 
   whileHover={animationComplete ? { scale: 1.1 } : {}}
```

I've also tried to add the following to whileHover:

```
whileHover={animationComplete === true ? { scale: 1.1 } : ""}
```

The hover animation still plays if the user hover's on the component while the intro animation is playing